# CMFCPropertyGridProperty issue with "Delete"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

When I use CMFCPropertyGridProperty in my application I have an issue with manipulating values during runtime.
The 'Delete' key does not work. In the Debug version it works, but not in Release.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give a lot of information so I'm just picking up the fact that you have different behaviour between Debug and Release builds. This is often due to problems with uninitialized variables - often bools - so first check you code to make sure that you don't have a problem like that. In particular, a bool will be initialised to zero in a Debug build but may be non-zero in a Release build - this can then affect the logic in your application.